# How to parse CSV with a Dataset based on a case class?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to parse a CSV with the new Spark 1.6.0 API Dataset. Anyway I am having some problems to do that. I want to create a `case class` for each of the CSV lines.

This is the code:

```
case class MyData (forename:String, surname:String, age:Integer)

    def toMyData(text: String): Dataset[MyData] = {
      val splits: Array[String] = text.split("\t")
      Seq(MyData(
        forename = splits(0),
        surname = splits(1),
        age = splits(2).asInstanceOf[Integer]
      )).toDS()
    }

    val lines:Dataset[MyData] = sqlContext.read.text("/data/mydata.csv").as[MyData]
    lines.map(r => toMyData(r)).foreach(println)
```

My `toMyData` is just a sort of `Encoder` but I don't know how to do that properly following the API.

Any idea?

**EDIT:**

I have changed the code in this way but I cannot make it even compile:

```
val lines:Dataset[MyData] = sqlContext.read.text("/data/mydata.csv").as[MyData]
    lines.map(r => toMyData(r)).foreach(println)

def toMyData(text: String): Dataset[MyData] = {
      val df = sc.parallelize(Seq(text)).toDF("value")

      df.map(_.getString(0).split("\t") match {
        case Array(fn, sn, age) =>
          MyData(fn, sn, age.asInstanceOf[Integer])
      }).toDS

    }

    sqlContext.read.text("/data/mydata.csv").as[String].map(r => toMyData(r)).collect().foreach(println)
```

as I got:

```
Error:(50, 10) value toDS is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[MyData]
possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDS'?
      }).toDS
         ^
Error:(54, 133) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing sqlContext.implicits._  Support for serializing other types will be added in future releases.
    sqlContext.read.text("/data/mydata.csv").as[String].map(r => toMyData(r)).collect().foreach(println)
```

Answer (score 4):

Ignoring format validation and exception handling:

```
//  Simulate sqlContext.read.text("/data/mydata.csv")
val df = sc.parallelize(Seq("John\tDoe\t22")).toDF("value")

df.rdd.map(_.getString(0).split("\t") match {
  case Array(fn, sn, age) => MyData(fn, sn, age.toInt)
}).toDS
```

or without converting to RDDs:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.regexp_extract

val pattern = "^(.*?)\t(.*?)\t(.*)$"
val exprs = Seq(
  (1, "forename", "string"), (2, "surname", "string"), (3, "age", "integer")
).map{case (i, n, t) => regexp_extract($"value", pattern, i).alias(n).cast(t)}

df
  .select(exprs: _*)  // Convert to (StringType, StringType, IntegerType)
  .as[MyData]  // cast
```

Summary:

- don't use nested actions, transformations or DDS.
- read how `asInstanceOf` works before using it. It is not applicable here.

Comment: I am thinking the method ```.as[String].transform(r => toMyData(r))``` has any sense. Anyway I am going to try your solution too. Thanks

Comment: `toMyData` placed inside transformation simply cannot work. Dataset is a distributed structure and cannot be nested.

Comment: No, it doesn't. Double check the types. Map function is of type `Row => MyData` not `Row => DataSet[MyData]`.

Comment: The @zero323 answer works perfectly, all you have to do is change `val df =..` to `sqlContext.read.text("")` to get the DF with a string per row?